# Pinescript Increment Swing Low count or Reset

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

I am trying to increment to create a variable that will increment if they meet a specific conditions. I am trying to use valuewhen syntax but having a hard time to make it work.

Basically I searching for Swing low ( this i was able to do it) but if my current swing low is higher than the previous one than i want to increment the count by 1 and if my the current swing low is lower than my previous one i want to reset the count to 1

Here is the output that i have today

[image]
With this code

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// test
study(title="Swing High Swing Low", shorttitle="Swing High Swing Low" , overlay = true)
HighOfCandle =  high*1
LowOfCandle = low*1
CloseOfCandle = close*1
OpenOfCandle = open*1 
SizeOfCandle = abs(HighOfCandle-LowOfCandle)
SwingLow = ((LowOfCandle > LowOfCandle[1]) and  ( LowOfCandle[1] < LowOfCandle[2])) ?nz(SwingLow[1])+1:0
plotchar(SwingLow, title="SwingLow",  text="SWL" , location=location.belowbar,offset=-1, color=green, char="")
SwingLowCount = SwingLow - valuewhen(SwingLow < SwingLow[1], SwingLow , 1 )
plotchar(SwingLowCount==1,char="1",color=orange,location=location.abovebar,transp=0,offset=-1)
plotchar(SwingLowCount==2,char="2",color=orange,location=location.abovebar,transp=0,offset=-1)
plotchar(SwingLowCount==3,char="3",color=orange,location=location.abovebar,transp=0,offset=-1)
```

And here is the expected output i would like to have
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the pine version 4 syntax, I removed the offset argument to properly debug the low count.

```
// @version=4
study(title="Swing High Swing Low", shorttitle="Swing High Swing Low" , overlay = true)
HighOfCandle =  high*1
LowOfCandle = low*1
CloseOfCandle = close*1
OpenOfCandle = open*1 
SizeOfCandle = abs(HighOfCandle-LowOfCandle)
SwingLow = ((LowOfCandle > LowOfCandle[1]) and  (LowOfCandle[1] < LowOfCandle[2]))
   
// Value to compare
var float valueSwingLow = na
valueSwingLow := SwingLow ? low : valueSwingLow[1]

// Start the count
var int SwingLowCount = na
SwingLowCount := valueSwingLow > valueSwingLow[1] ? SwingLowCount + 1 : valueSwingLow < valueSwingLow[1] ? 1 : SwingLowCount[1]

// Offset removed
plotchar(SwingLow, title="SwingLow",  text="SWL" , location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, char="")
plotchar(SwingLowCount==1 and SwingLow, char = "1", color = color.orange, location = location.abovebar, transp = 0)
plotchar(SwingLowCount==2 and SwingLow, char = "2", color = color.orange, location = location.abovebar, transp = 0)
plotchar(SwingLowCount==3 and SwingLow, char = "3", color = color.orange, location = location.abovebar, transp = 0)
plotchar(SwingLowCount==4 and SwingLow, char = "4", color = color.orange, location = location.abovebar, transp = 0)
plotchar(SwingLowCount==5 and SwingLow, char = "5", color = color.orange, location = location.abovebar, transp = 0)
plotchar(SwingLowCount==6 and SwingLow, char = "6", color = color.orange, location = location.abovebar, transp = 0)
```

Comment: Thanks , love to logic . I for some reason have some problems to understand the ternary , but i will study correctly your answer. In between i did found another way looking at the version 4 documentation ```var s = 0.0
if close >= open
    s := s + 1``` I adapted it to reset s or increment s depending on the condition